# find all classes which implemented another class in dart

Tags: flutter, dart, class, reflection, abstract-class

I have a base generic class, and I want to find all classes which implements this class, do we have such thing in dart?

for clarifying this is my base class

```
abstract class IBaseClass<T>{
    void (T command);
}
```

and these are its implementation:

```
class CreateHandler implements IBaseClass<CreateCommand>{
    void (CreateCommand command)
    {
        //do something
    }
}

class DeleteHandler implements IBaseClass<DeleteCommand>{
    void (DeleteCommand command)
    {
        //do something
    }
}
```

Do we have something to pass base class to it and it returns these two classes?
Maybe like this:

```
var implementations = GetImplementationsForClass(Typeof(IBaseClass<>));
```

Comment: "do we have such thing in dart?" - no

Comment: Yes, `dartdoc` lists all known implementations and subtypes of a class.  If you're willing to write code to do static analysis on your project, you could do the same thing.  Of course, it could only tell you about classes in your project that derive from your base class, obviously not about potential derived classes in packages it doesn't know about.

Comment: sure I want just to know about my own code not the packages. thank you, I will check @jamesdlin